# Filesetattr is not available with XE3 (Firemonkey)

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I want create a hidden ini file under macosX environment with Firemonkey (XE3).
But unfortunaly this command is not known anymore in system.utilys

Somebody tips?

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac, there are two ways to make file "hidden" or "invisible".

Like Linux or Unix, [you can start the filename with a dot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) (.).

You can also use the [setfile](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20011018172352562) tool that ships with Xcode to set attributes to make it invisible (`[setfile a -V filename][3]`).

Depending on the way, you will have to replace the Win32 specific `SetFileAttr` call with a Mac specific rename, or find out which API `setfile` uses to set the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

In UNIX (and in this layer Mac OS is largely spin-off from FreeBSD) there is no "hidden" flag on file, instead special files should have their name started with dot.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-file

So if you want to hide a file - rename it.

That is not the question about Delphi = that is the question of operating system, Windows vs UNIX.

Open console/terminal/whatever they call command prompt in Apple, go to ur home folder and issue two commands: *ls* and *ls -a* - compare the file lists in output.

Well, for starters you can do it in Linux - http://bellard.org/jslinux/ - wait few seconds for it to boot, then issue *ls*, *ls -l*, *ls -a*, *ls -la* and see the difference.

Dot-files are treated specially and hidden by default.